# SQL server index on date best practice

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a very simple table containing a `user_id`, `_project_id`, `day` and `hours` column. A simple pivot query is used to calculate the amount of hours spent on each project on a daily basis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         hours, project_id,
         LEFT(DATENAME(dw, day), 3) AS workday
     FROM
         activities
     WHERE
         user_id = '" . $user . "' 
         AND DATEPART(wk, day) = '" . $week . "' 
         AND DATEPART(yyyy, day) = '" . $year . "') temp
PIVOT (
                sum([hours])
                for workday in ([mon],[tue],[wed],[thu],[fri])
            ) AS pvt
            ORDER BY project;
```

The $user, `$week` and `$year` parameters are HTML Form parameters. Because of the `DATEPART` function in the `WHERE` clause, would it improve performance to create an extra column '`week`' and an extra column '`year`' to the table and add an index to both columns? Or would it be sufficient to add an index to the day column?

Comment: does this pivot query run?

Comment: Instead of looking for indexes you should be worrying about SQL Injection. Change your query to use parameters if you want to avoid injection attacks

Comment: Applying functions to fields prevents the optimizer from using any underlying indexes. If you want to search for week days, either add a separate WeekDay column, or join with a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) on day and filter by the Calendar table's weekday column and year

Comment: Yes, this pivot query run. Maybe I made a typo simplifying, but it runs OK. And I am using Laravel Framework, so SQL Injection is not an issue.